# How to set 'down' property to Jquery accordion animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-ui-accordion

According to [jQuery UI's formal API document](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-animate), we can set 'down' property to animate.

> **Multiple types supported:**
>
> - **Boolean:** A value of false will disable animations.
> - **Number:** Duration in milliseconds with default easing.
> - **String:** Name of easing to use with default duration.
> - **Object:** An object containing easing and duration properties to configure animations.
>
>   - Can also contain a down property with any of the above options.
>   - "Down" animations occur when the panel being activated has a lower index than the currently active panel.

If I have codes like this:

```
var accOpts = {
    easing: "linear",
    duration: "fast",
}

#("#accordion").accordion({
    animate: accOpts,
});
```

How can I really set 'down' property?

Comment: Zhe, how do you want to use the 'down' property? Do you need to animate the panels vertically? Or do you want to control the direction of the easing? Please confirm what you need this property to do so we can make sure to provide the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks, @gibberish! Just like the JQuery document say, I want to configure the behavior when the panel being activated has a lower index than the currently active panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a boolean, number, string, or object, just as you would pass into `animate`. You just add it as a property to your `accOpts` object. If you set it to 1000, for example, it will take one second when going backwards, instead of "fast" when going forward. I've shown an example with an object, and thrown in some variations as comments.

```js
var accOpts = {
  easing: "linear",
  duration: "fast",
  down: {
    easing: "easeInOutQuart",
    duration: 1000
  }
  
  //down: false
  //down: "easeInOutQuart"
  //down: 1000
}

$("#accordion").accordion({
  animate: accOpts,
});
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
      a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam
      nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```